# Highcharts tooltips with embedded sparklines

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create a map with tooltips that show some additional data shown in the tooltip as a collection of sparklines. Basically I want to achieve a similar effect to this [map](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/us/coronavirus-us-cases.html?name=styln-coronavirus-national&region=TOP_BANNER&label=undefined&module=undefined&block=storyline_menu_recirc&action=click&pgtype=Interactive&impression_id=95c1e6b2-0f38-11eb-80ff-dd312df20dfb&variant=undefined). I have looked through the Highcharts [tooltip formatter documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) but it seems that the HTML code that I can pass to the formatter function is quite limited.

So in nutshell, is there way to embed a sparkline in a Highcharts tooltip or is this not really possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a chart in a tooltip by using a `setTimeout` callback function:

```
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                Highcharts.chart('tooltip-chart', {
                    ...
                });
            }, 10)

            return '<div style="width: 100px; height: 60px;" id="tooltip-chart"></div>';
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yqtvr5Lm/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter